# Data "eaten up" on file upload to Amazon S3 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an xml file to an Amazon S3 server. My code in ruby goes like this:-

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store("dir/data.xml",
                            "#{xml.target!}",
                            "bucket",
                            :access => :private,
                            :content_type => 'text/xml')
```

The xml is an RSS feed file. When I download the uploaded file from the server, the file is missing the last line from the file.

```
</rss>
```

Removing the optional parameter content-type has no effect on the output. However, changing the data component to insert additional characters makes those missing characters appear corectly.

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store("dir/data.xml",
                                "#{xml.target!}         ",
                                "bucket",
                                :access => :private,
                                :content_type => 'text/xml')
```

Even though this solves my problem, I am a little reluctant to use this code in production. Also, I would like to know what is going wrong?

As a matter of fact, when I write to a file on my local machine, it works correctly.

```
file = File.new("/path/feed.xml", "w")
    file.write(xml.target!)
    file.close
```

Update: I am facing the same problem while uploading a csv file as well. I notice that for very large files, even more data is truncated. For the xml file, not only the closing rss tag, but a few other tags are also missing. Similarly for the csv file. How do I resolve these?

Comment: does your file end in a newline? Perhaps something is being line-buffered incorrectly?

Comment: yup, its ending in a newline.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the output for `"#{xml.target!}"` does indeed contain all of the correct information? Why are you putting `xml.target!` in a string in the first place? I'm guessing this is really something to do with the "target" not having had the final tag applied to it, yet. What type of object is the target? (I assume `xml` is a Builder::XmlMarkup?)

Comment: xml.target! contains the correct data with the last tag included. That is why writing to a file on the local machine works perfectly(last code example). Also, xml is indeed Builder::XmlMarlup. Even without the string quotes around xml.target!, it faces the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you try changing your file format to unix and then try the transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending the xml.target! as data was somehow resulting in this problem. In order to solve this I created a new string using StringIO.new.

For csv, i used something like this :-

```
 csv_string = StringIO.new(csv_string)
```